Have I been hacked
Someone send me an email telling me I have been hacked..
It all seems nonsense

He hacked my PC, he says, but that seems not true, as he would have used ransomware
He told me my old password was my password but it is an old password from long ago) (password for email he is contacting me on)
He didn't change any of my details in my hotmail account (or any other accounts).. no recovery email change, no password change, and so on

Only thing made me believe him was that the email he sent from is exactly identical to mine.. even when I try to click to have the real info, correct details.. it stills shows mine
I had a nice idea to download eml.. put it in viewer to say what the real value is.. ' from ' part is identical my email exactly.
Note I tried the feature which view actual account sent from when clicking the first one.. (other emails show normally, typically)
This persons email, however, still shows mine
Someone told me this spoofing can work against outlook it self without detecting actual address.
What can I do to confirm that this is a non harmful claim of hacking..
Please note I am securing everything on my PC, accounts,.. and already started using 1password

Btw, in case you are wondering why people are voting you down, most people will not be able to determine by your question alone if you are truly hacked or not and would like to see the email. Luckily, I've seen so many spam emails that I know the signs inside out, and one of them is sending the email from your own name.

No, you have definitely not been hacked. This is an email that circles around a lot from time to time.
These are scammers who buy databases with email addresses in them, and often a password (login info).
The hacker then sends an email to everyone in the list, and spoofs the headers, so it appears to come from you (this is very easy to do). Without an SPF record on your email address and a spamfilter, the email is not stopped.
They will then send an email with a lenghty text (its always the same text) how they hacked your computer and gathered evidence and possibly a claim to damage your computer.
At the end of the email, they'll drop a bitcoin address and tell you to send money there and they'll then destroy all the stuff they have on you.
This is literally all they can do (send the email) and hope that you're gullable and buy the story.
Just delete it.
Fun fact, the way I setup my email system, I have multiple email aliasses that all drop in the same mailbox. When a spamround like this happens, I often get 3 or 4 emials with all the same text, only the to address and name changed, and the "password" too of course.
So yeah, this is fake.
If you want to have some fun, copy some of the standard text in the email and google it. You'll be surprised that others got the exact same email.
Do note, the text in the emial seems to change everytime they do one of these mailings. But over the past 4 or so years, I think I had 10 waves of these, if not more.
